# Solution for constraints - need help

Tags: transforms, constraints

Hi fellas I have a problem with solving an issue possible to find in the .blend file provided.

If You open the file there is a simple scene with constraints applied to the AXIS parenting two objects. Rotating the "toroid" along the Y GLOBAL rotates the axis along Z LOCAL. Problem is that to work as designed all objects has to be rotated simultaneously cause parenting axis to the toroid somehow break the global-local thing so to keep the axis in place all objects has to be rotated.

To test the function simply select ALL objects from the front view and rotate along Y so You could see how its working. Problem is when the rotation is finished, the next rotation does not work (global rotation somehow "resets" to 0,0,0 again imo and whole thing break-up).

Rotate for example for 30 degrees along Y, confirm it and try to rotate again to see what Im talking about. I need to solve this somehow but failed using all combinations in mind. Probably something else than constraints will be needed but dunno what.

Appreciate any idea and solutions buddies!

Sincerely, Jan

[image]

Comment: It seems to me that one problem is that you don't have the local Y axis of the empty, axle, or wing pointing in the direction you want, which I assume is along the major axis of the axle.  Would changing that help? I also think you might want a copy rotation constraint on the empty with the toroid as target with only the Y axis copied world -> local.

Comment: Hi could You "repair" my file and re-send? In fact I dont really understand that "axis axle major pointing along" thing ;).

Comment: I don't have an alternative that works yet, but I have tried to clarify my comment below.